# why EMR SPARK job fails when task group node is lost?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I am using AWS emr-5.0.0 to run a small cluster that consists of the following notes:

- 1 Master - AWS on demand instance
- 1 CORE - AWS on demand instance
- 2 TASK - AWS SPOT instance

All of them are x3.xlarge machines.

I run a python spark application with two stages.

The problem is that when I manually terminate one of the TASK instances (or it gets terminated due to spot price change) the entire spark job fails.

I would expect that SPARK would just continue running the lost tasks on remaining nodes. Please explain why it does not happen.

Below is the log, master ip is 172-31-1-0, core instance it is 172-31-1-173, the lost not ip is 172-31-3-81).

[log file (stderr and stdout from spark-submit)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4WOvWmwTh_rSDRVVC14Wlo2Mjg)

Comment: Which mode do you use to submit your application? yarn-cluster, yarn-client or standalone? My only guess for such behavior is that you are executing the application with yarn-cluster, and then the application master resides on one of the task nodes, and then when the task node fails, the application master get restarted.

Comment: i ssh to master node and run spark-submit. I am using client mode (default is spark)